# WFFM throw folder error 8.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

WFFM throw folder error. Please find the screen shot.I have not written any code. I just created form and bind that into content tree only.It's working on Sitecore preview mode.

[image]

Formdata table not available in mongodb analytics database.
[image]

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: folder
>   Source: Sitecore.Forms.Core
>     at Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.GetThemeName(Item form, ID >fieldId)
>     at Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.GetThemeUrl(Item form, >Boolean deviceDependant)
>     at Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.ScriptsTags(Item form, >Item contextItem)
>     at Sitecore.Form.Core.Configuration.ThemesManager.RegisterCssScript(Page >page, Item form, Item contextItem)
>     at Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SitecoreSimpleFormAscx.OnInit(EventArgs e)
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
>     at Sitecore.Form.Core.Renderings.FormRender.OnInit(EventArgs e)
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>     at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean >includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Is your CM and CD one instance or different servers? Did you verify that everything is published correctly and in case of multiple servers, installed on all servers?

Comment: It's my local instance for practice purpose :)

Comment: did you Check sitecore log files for more information about the error?

Comment: I have updated the post with logs.